# Python (Softimage input box) and function arguments

Tags: python, function, inputbox

I'm new to programming (about a week old). I've run into a little problem in Python, couldn't find anything helpful in the searches (new to that here as well).

The script I made below is working if I just don't use softimage's inputbox

```
l1 = ['Taskmaster', 'Red Skull', 'Zemo']
l2 = ['Capt. America', 'Iron Man', 'Thor']

def findguy (where, inputguy):
    a = "not here"
    for i in (range(len(where))):
        if where[i] == inputguy:
            a = "yes here"
    print a

#findguy (l1, 'Taskmaster')

x = Application.XSIInputbox ("Who are you looking for?","find character")
y = Application.XSIInputbox ('Which list?','Search List')


findguy (y, x)
```

If I just use findguy(type the inputs here directly) the code works, but if I try to input it through the input box in Softimage it just keeps returning "not here"

If anyone could be kind enough to help this week old struggling self learner, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gogo

Comment: print x and y so you can see what you're working with. Makes it easier to find out where the problem lies

Comment: Thanks - I have tried that. printing both x and y returns my input exactly. the function itself seems to be ignoring whatever the inputs are. :(

Comment: Can you post a sample of what input you are testing with?

Comment: I'm not that good at explaining (especially as a beginning self learner who doesn't know programming terminology) - so I'll show it instead:

Comment: http://youtu.be/B9o8MWPDYnY

Comment: I cannot watch the vid here, I was just asking what x and y you tried that didn't work

Comment: x - I am asked to input any of the names on either list provided above (l1 and l2) and y - I am asked to input the name of the list - basically I should just input l1 or l2. - the program will then tell me whether or not what I entered in the input box for x can be found in the list I entered for input y. --- if I manually hardcode the arguments (like in this example: findguy (l1, 'Taskmaster')) the code is running fine, when I hardcode argument 1 (the list) it still works while I use input X in argument 2. but it is when I try to input y only that the code just keeps saying "not here"

Comment: apologies for how I explain things - im not familiar with the proper terminology, just describing the situation as best as I can. Thanks!

Comment: That is ok, thanks to your help i found the error and see my answer below for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method works fine. The problem lies in the fact that the input you get from

```
y = Application.XSIInputbox ('Which list?','Search List')
```

will be a string. So `y` is a string and not a list. The same applies to `x` of course but that doesn't give an issue because your lists contain only strings.

What happens is your function call actually looks like this (example)

```
findguy('l1', 'Zemo')
```

and then on this line

```
if where[i] == inputguy:
```

it will compare the characters of `l1`, being `l` and `1` to `inputguy`. Of course that keeps being false so you get "not here" as output.

What you want is your function call to look like this instead

```
findguy(l1, 'Zemo')
```

This can be achieved by doing something like this:

```
y = Application.XSIInputbox ('Which list?','Search List')
if y == "l1":
    y = l1
elif y == "l2":
    y = l2
```

This simply 'picks' a list based on your input and passes that to `findguy`. In your situation this would be an O.K. solution but if your code was only an example and your actual code has more lists, or will have in the future you should look for a better solution. A suggestion would be to store your guys in a dictionary instead:

```
guys = {'l1': ['Taskmaster', 'Red Skull', 'Zemo'], 'l2': ['Capt. America', 'Iron Man', 'Thor']}
```

Then you can process your input with

```
x = Application.XSIInputbox ("Who are you looking for?","find character")
y = Application.XSIInputbox ('Which list?','Search List')

findguy (guys[y], x)
```

This works because the dictionary's keys are strings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see, it makes sense why I kept going in circles. Will note this down. Thanks!